# Joi Array validation unable to cast to array

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I am using `Joi` for schema validation. I have an array of object's that i want to be validated with `Joi`. Here is the code:

```
const joi = require("joi");

function validateUser(user) {
  let phone = joi.object().keys({
    id: joi.string().required(),
    phoneNumber: joi.string().required()
  });

  const schema = {
    firstName: joi.string().required(),
    lastName: joi.string().required(),
    email: joi
      .string()
      .email()
      .required(),
    phoneNumbers: joi.array().items(phone)
  };

  return joi.validate(user, schema).error;
}
```

This is the `user` object that i am passing to `validateUser` function.

```
{
  firstName: 'User',
  lastName: 'One',
  email: 'userone@gmail.com'
  phoneNumbers: [
    {
      id: '03bb22cc-499a-4464-af08-af64d5a52675',
      phoneNumber: '13001234567'
    },
    {
      id: '50e32458-756b-4aaa-b3dc-19a2f696ab6c',
      phoneNumber: '13031234567'
    }
  ]
}
```

But, it is showing me the following error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: user validation failed: phoneNumbers: Cast to Array failed for value "[
  {
    id: '03bb22cc-499a-4464-af08-af64d5a52675',
    phoneNumber: '13001234567'
  },
  {
    id: '50e32458-756b-4aaa-b3dc-19a2f696ab6c',
    phoneNumber: '13031234567'
  }
]" at path "phoneNumbers"
```

I don't know what is happening here. Could you please propose a solution to this?

Comment: Print out your `user` object.

Comment: @hoangdv updated the question with `user` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Joi` schema is correct according to the Official Documentation. The issue was with my `Mongoose` Schema. Previously it was:

```
const User = mongoose.model(
  "user",
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      phoneNumbers: {
        type: [String],
        default: []
      }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  )
);
```

It worked fine when i changed it to:

```
const User = mongoose.model(
  "user",
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      phoneNumbers: {
        type: [{ id: String, phoneNumber: String}],
        default: []
      }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  )
);
```